# Improving tcl/tk command prompt

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

My code is below.

1. I want that cursor should come right of `>` 
   i.e. `>|`   ( instead of `|>` )
2. When someone tries to erase or press any keyboard key to upper commands,
   it should get back to current command area without erasing/modifying upper area commands
   (or their outputs)
3. In case of error, all error output should come in red color.
   Currently, only some error lines are in red color only.

Please suggest how to add changes to the current code to facilitate above points.

## My code

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
set cur 1.0
set ncur 1
set prev_cmd ""

proc printlog {msg {typ ""}} {
    global .f.t cur ncur
    .f.t insert end "\n$msg\n>"
    set cur [.f.t search -count length $msg $cur end]
    set ncur [expr round($cur)]
    .f.t see end

    if {$typ == "error"} {
        .f.t tag add foo $cur $ncur.end
        .f.t tag configure foo -foreground red
    }   elseif {$typ == "yellow"} {
        .f.t tag add foo $cur $ncur.end
        .f.t tag configure foo -foreground yellow -background #696969
    }
}

frame .f
pack .f -fill both -anchor n
text .f.t -yscrollcommand {.f.s set}
scrollbar .f.s -command {.f.t yview}
pack .f.s -side right -fill y
pack .f.t -fill both -expand 1

.f.t insert end ">"

proc processcmd {} {
    global .f.t prev_cmd
    set prev_cmd [.f.t get 1.0 end]
    set l [string length $prev_cmd]
    set temp ""
    for { set a $l}  {$a > -1} {incr a -1} {
        set c [string index $prev_cmd $a]
        if {$c == ">"} {
            break
        } else {
            set temp $c$temp
        }
}
    set prev_cmd $temp
    if {[catch {set output [eval $prev_cmd]} errmsg]} {
        if {[catch {set output [eval exec $prev_cmd]} errmsg]} {
            if {[catch {set output [exec $prev_cmd]} errmsg]} {
            printlog "$errmsg" "error"
            return
            }
        }
    }
    printlog $output
}
bind .f.t <Return> {
    processcmd
    tk::TextSetCursor %W {insert display linestart}
}
focus .f.t
bind .f.t <Up> {
   if {$prev_cmd ne ""} {
      .f.t insert end $prev_cmd
      break
   }
}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This Is not related to python, please don't use the "tkinter" tag.

Comment: @Yoshikage Kira
I have not tagged python.
It is related to tkinter, that's why tagged tkinter.

Comment: Have you looked at how Tk's `console` command's widget works? Or how the TkCon application works? They do the sorts of things you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The code for doing what you're asking for is a bit long. In particular, while there are implementations of consoles, they're quite a bit of code, to the point of being too long to put in an answer here and have it continue to be comprehensible.

Key resources:

- [tk/library/console.tcl](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=library/console.tcl&ci=tip) — this is the implementation of the majority of the `console` command in Tk. (There's a few bits in C, but they're to do with isolating the console from the main interpreter, which isn't stuff you need to care about.)
- [TkCon](https://github.com/wjoye/tkcon) — this project is effectively a replacement for the `console` command that does an even better job of it (and supports many other features besides).

---

The key technique that you are not yet taking advantage of is *marks*. In particular, you want a *left-gravity* mark that you put at the end of the prompt so that you know where the editable range of text actually is. (Having left gravity means that inserts at the mark go after the mark.) Without that, it's really difficult to keep track of whether the point where the cursor is is one that allows an insertion.

Comment: Hi Donald fellows, thank you for helping me always !!
I wont need separate console, this (above code) is part of my tcl/tk project.
I wrote most of the code for console, please suggest required code changes to support above functionalities.